# Can I use the function menu_tree() in Drupal 7 to customize a menu and add CSS classes?

Tags: theming, routes

Can I use the function `menu_tree()` in Drupal 7 to customize a menu and add CSS classes? I've tried to customize a main_menu by adding CSS classes: Is it the right way?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to add custom classes to menu items in Drupal 7 is the [Menu Attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module.

If you really want to do this programmatically, then you can override the [theme_menu_link()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7) function in your theme's template.php file. Be sure to read the drupal.org documentation on [Overriding Themable Output](http://drupal.org/node/173880).